# Unable to solve mutidex issue after migrating to androidx

Tags: android, androidx

My App has minsdkversion 16 and have just migrated to androidx. It initially started giving multidex issue and after looking into few suggestions here,
have added `"multiDexEnabled true"` under defaultConfig in build grade. During migration to androidx, gradle properties took the values `"android.enableJetifier=true android.useAndroidX=true"`. Now if i try to generate signed apk, it still throws multidex issue. Another suggestion here was to add the multidex lib and add to application tag in manifest.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
<application
        android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

Tried all sorts of combination of these config suggestion. Still multidex error.

Final gradle.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.example.problem"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'

   }
```

Comment: What multidex issue? I didn't understand, what is logcat/console saying?

Comment: which gradle version are you using? Try to clean the project first.

Comment: hi Alberto, i have cleaned, restarted etc couple of times already

Comment: please if you are using android studio, add the logCat error in order to know what is happenning

Comment: apologies for not able to paste the logcat as i am re-installing android studio.

Comment: Strange.... but after re-installation of android studio....problem is solved. :)